# Producer/Consumer Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, threadpool

I want to produce one item and consume just that one. The goal here is to use the CountdownEvent. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here and how can I improve this example to make this work? Bellow I am adding the code

```
class Program
{
    private static int counter = 1;
    static Queue<Product> products = new Queue<Product>();
    static readonly object locker = new object();
    static CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Producer());
        Task.Run(() => Consumer());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Producer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var product = new Product()
            {
                Number = counter,
                Name = "Product " + counter++
            };

            lock (locker)
            {
                //Adding one element
                Console.WriteLine("Producing: " + product);
                products.Enqueue(product);

                countdown.Wait();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    static void Consumer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                //wait until exist one element
                if (!products.Any())
                  continue;

                var product = products.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine("Consuming: " + product);
                countdown.Signal();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: Are you sure you want to fit Countdownevent here?

Comment: There's just no point to doing it this way.  You get the exact same outcome by having the producer thread also execute the consuming code.  Minus a bunch of unnecessary and icky synchronization code.